# Nice scroll not working on <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nicescroll

Nice scroll functionality is not working on p tag. Please see my following code snippet

```js
$(".newsDesc").niceScroll();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="newsDesc text-justify">

  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam lorem ipsum lorem particular?

</p>
```

and i include this file:

```
<script src="assets/js/nicescroll.js"></script>
```

If I put nice scroll on any div it works fine but on the

tag it is not working? any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: Please check in console is it show any error or not?

Comment: no errors at all @Jinesh

Comment: is your text overflowing, do you have `overflow:hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set height and with for p tag. `$(document).ready(function() { var nc = $(".newsDesc").niceScroll();});
<style>.newsDesc {width : 100px;height : 200px;border : 1px solid red;   cursor:default;}</style>`

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` tags are [not supported in `niceScroll`](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll). However div, Iframe, textarea, and document page (body) scrollbars **are** supported.

From the [documentation](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/how-to-use/) and using [this](https://jsfiddle.net/inuyaksa/thohu1se/) example: `niceScroll` requires both a **container** and a **wrapper** div in order to *specify the bounds for scrolling*. You also need to specify the target wrapper when initialising the `niceScroll()` function.

Also you are missing some `css` classes in your example, see snippet below:

```js
$(".newsDesc").niceScroll("div.nice-wrapper", {
  cursorwidth: "12px"
});
```

```css
.newsDesc {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 280px;
}

.nice-wrapper {}

.nicescroll-rails {
  background-color: white;;
}

.nicescroll-cursors {
  border: none !important;
  background-color: purple !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container newsDesc">
  <div class="nice-wrapper">
    <h2> paragraph 1</h2>
    <p class="text-justify">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
      sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
      incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam lorem ipsum lorem particular?
    </p>
    <h2> paragraph 2</h2>
    <p class="text-justify">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
      sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
      incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam lorem ipsum lorem particular?
    </p>
    <h2> paragraph 3</h2>
    <p class="text-justify">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
      sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
      incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam lorem ipsum lorem particular?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").niceScroll({
    cursorborder: "1px solid aquamarine",
    cursorwidth: "8px"
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="newsDesc text-justify" style="text-align: justify;">
  <h1>content</h1>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
  quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
  tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam lorem ipsum lorem particular?
  <h1>content</h1>
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam lorem ipsum lorem particular?
  <h1>content</h1>
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam lorem ipsum lorem particular?
</p>
```